# Is Cocona a Reyvateil?

Tags: ar-tonelico

In Phase 1 of *Ar Tonelico 2: Melody of Metafalicia* when Croix's group is heading back to Pastalia after Cloche collapsed Cocona becomes targeted by Grand Bell Knights because she is infected with I.P.D.

To my understanding I.P.D can only be contracted by Reyvateil's yet no one bats an eye about Cocona being a Reyvateil rather her level of infection (thus the suprise deployment). both Luca and Cloche has had to have the Life Extending Agent administrated to them but Cocona has yet to receive one and while i've only just started Phase 3 there seem to be no indication Cocona is a Reyvateil (ie. she's not reading Hymmnos, not using Song Magic).

So is Cocona a Reyvateil? if so how far developed is she as a Reyvateil in comparison to Luca and Cloche

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [EXA_PICO wikia](http://artonelico.wikia.com/wiki/Reyvateil), Cocona is a 3rd generation IPD Reyvateil.
This, of course, needs a bit more explanation.

Reyvateils are artificial life forms created to use Song Magic. There are Purebloods and Halfbloods Reyvateil.

There are sub-classification under those two categories, but let's focus on Cocona.

By being a 3rd generation Reyvateil, it means Cocona was born from a Reyvateil mother and a human father. Normally, those children tend to be normal humans, but there are cases in which the Reyvateil genes are strong, causing the Song Servers to recognize such human as a Reyvateil.
As such, those Reyvateils tend to have a shorter life span, since their human body is not made to endure the constant energy surge form using Song Magic.
Yet, differently from Pureblood Reyvateils, they can live outside of their tower's range. That makes their Reyvateil part go dormant and they can live as normal humans.

Cocona is also an IPD, meaning she does not connect to the "correct" server, but to the Infel Phira server. The whole IPD situation is from the game's story and I guess there is no need to delve to deep on it.

So, to cut it short, I guess the fact that Cocona was a 3rd generation Reyvateil was already known or obvious to the other characters, since 3rd generation Reyvateils were not uncommon.